# ElasticSearch difference aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

This is a piece of my data stored :

```
[
  {
    "name": "disk.device.write.requests",
    "type": "cumulative",
    "unit": "request",
    "volume": 0,
    "user_id": "b0407ee332f6474c87d1e666262d4783",
    "project_id": "75ebb9556f8c4e36b0d3e722a57ff3bb",
    "resource_id": "7837ab92-5eb7-4cdc-9da3-5f1d2a385841-hda",
    "timestamp": "2021-11-14T13:28:45.873289",
    "resource_metadata": {
      "display_name": "ali",
      "name": "instance-00000004",
      "instance_id": "7837ab92-5eb7-4cdc-9da3-5f1d2a385841",
      "instance_type": "Tochal",
      "host": "b34b47c6129603ae3d0387bfa8bf8fe487b0a8424d7e3debb6c69b6d",
      "instance_host": "os",
      "flavor": {
        "id": "t1",
        "name": "Tochal",
        "vcpus": 4,
        "ram": 4096,
        "disk": 40,
        "ephemeral": 0,
        "swap": 0
      },
      "status": "active",
      "state": "running",
      "task_state": "",
      "image": {
        "id": "f77ec16e-1c4e-4ed7-b340-b537ab008367"
      },
      "image_ref": "f77ec16e-1c4e-4ed7-b340-b537ab008367",
      "image_ref_url": null,
      "architecture": "x86_64",
      "os_type": "hvm",
      "vcpus": 4,
      "memory_mb": 4096,
      "disk_gb": 40,
      "ephemeral_gb": 0,
      "root_gb": 40,
      "disk_name": "hda"
    },
    "source": "openstack",
    "id": "cafd91ab-454e-11ec-b8ba-3b125e027b37",
    "monotonic_time": null
  }
...]
```

I've written an aggregation to group data in one hour by `name` field for a project:

```
{
      index: 'cm',
      size: 0,
      pretty: true,
      body: {
        query: {
          bool: {
            must: [
              {
                match: {
                  project_id: '75ebb9556f8c4e36b0d3e722a57ff3bb',
                },
              },
              {
                range: {
                  timestamp: {
                    gte: 'now-1H',
                  },
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        },
        aggs: {
          names: {
            terms: { field: 'name' },
            aggs: {
              myvalue: { sum: { field: 'volume' } },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    }
```

And it's output is:

```
        "aggregations": {
            "names": {
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                "sum_other_doc_count": 4,
                "buckets": [
                    {
                        "key": "disk.device.read.bytes",
                        "doc_count": 8,
                        "hatprice": {
                            "value": 2311073040
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "disk.device.read.requests",
                        "doc_count": 8,
                        "hatprice": {
                            "value": 68796
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "disk.device.write.bytes",
                        "doc_count": 8,
                        "hatprice": {
                            "value": 13117853696
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "disk.device.write.requests",
                        "doc_count": 8,
                        "hatprice": {
                            "value": 776618
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "cpu",
                        "doc_count": 4,
                        "hatprice": {
                            "value": 4541150000000
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "memory.usage",
                        "doc_count": 4,
                        "hatprice": {
                            "value": 1741
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "network.incoming.bytes",
                        "doc_count": 4,
                        "hatprice": {
                            "value": 532735722
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "network.incoming.packets",
                        "doc_count": 4,
                        "hatprice": {
                            "value": 864945
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "network.outgoing.bytes",
                        "doc_count": 4,
                        "hatprice": {
                            "value": 58562803
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "network.outgoing.packets",
                        "doc_count": 4,
                        "hatprice": {
                            "value": 439204
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

I need to aggregate base on `volume` field minus previous hour `volume` value.
Is it possible?

e.g: `network.incoming.bytes` in current hour. (not from first).

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved the problem using `SERIAL_DIFF` but not sure:

```
{
      index: 'cm',
      size: 0,
      pretty: true,
      body: {
        query: {
          bool: {
            must: [
              {
                match: {
                  project_id: '75ebb9556f8c4e36b0d3e722a57ff3bb',
                },
              },
              {
                range: {
                  timestamp: {
                    gte: 'now-2H',
                  },
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        },
        aggs: {
          names: {
            terms: { field: 'name' },
            aggs: {
              mydateh: {
                date_histogram: {
                  field: 'timestamp',
                  calendar_interval: 'hour',
                },
                aggs: {
                  volrate: { max: { field: 'volume' } },
                  diff: {
                    serial_diff: {
                      buckets_path: 'volrate',
                      lag: 1,
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    }
```